# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14' Invalid column name . SQL query

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp-classic

Hi I have having this error message

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>
> Invalid column name 'gonzalez'.

When I try to run this query I just made. This website has a search box that I type in that searches all the last names in corporate directory.

```
    SecurityQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbCorpDir.dbo.vwEmployees WHERE sn like '" & FormatDBTextSearch(Last_Name) & "' ORDER BY sn;"
```

this works fine in SSMS

```
    SELECT * FROM dbCorpDir.dbo.vwEmployees WHERE sn like 'gonzalez' ORDER BY sn;
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Could you have a single quote in your search string?  In any case, printing out the value of `SecurityQuery` *after* substitution makes the problem obvious in about 95% of the cases.

Comment: If you look at SecurityQuery variable to see what is in it, you'll find what is wrong. Query is simple and looks correct unless there is some special character in Last_Name that may cause problem. BTW, this query is not safe because of SQL Injection.

Comment: yes forgot to say we are aware of the sql injection but this site is internal only. so we are not that worried.

Comment: when i use  SELECT * FROM dbCorpDir.dbo.vwEmployees WHERE sn like 'gonzalez' ORDER BY sn;      Everything works fine in management studio.

Comment: Obviously, your application sends to sql server different query: `SELECT * FROM dbCorpDir.dbo.vwEmployees WHERE sn like gonzalez ORDER BY sn; ` Maybe you remove single quotes from the `SecurityQuery` before the execution?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin ok I removed the single quotes and now I have "ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1' 

Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal. 
"

Comment: Run Sql Profiler and find the exact string that is being sent to your server.

Comment: You do not have to remove single quotes. You must have it. What I'm saying, your app is not sending to SQL Server correct query you are expecting.

Comment: @granadaCoder I just tried to open this for the first time and it says I need to be a member of Sysadmin or have the alter trace permission. sorry I am a brand new low level employee without much permissions.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin ok i was thinking it needs to have the single quote for the  like statement to work right?   like  'something'

Comment: something I am finding weird is that it is searching for a column name in my table pertaining to what i type in the search box but I am trying to find a name that fits the description in my SN (sur name) column. It is thinking last-name = column name some how

Comment: can you try to use `[sn]` instead of `sn` ?

Comment: @Zam thank for for the suggestion. Unfortunately it still has the same error. I am having a headache over this.

Comment: Also is this asp.net or asp-classic?  It is usually not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys just for future reference I will post what I found.I removed the single quotes. But I needed to rename the output fields to the column names of the new database.(DUH)! I kept relying on the debugger telling me what line the error was on and it was wrong. Thanks again for all the help.

```
   SecurityQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbCorpDir.dbo.vwEmployees WHERE sn like " & FormatDBTextSearch(Last_Name) & " ORDER BY sn;"
```